# For locale "ar" (Arabic) the following quantities should also be defined: few, many, two, zero

Tags: android, string, android-activity

Getting error when translating Android String from EN TO AR.

"For locale "ar" (Arabic) the following quantities should also be defined: few, many, two, zero , This lint check looks at each translation of a  and makes sure that all the quantity strings considered by the given language are provided by this translation"

For the bellow string

```
  <plurals name="settings_import_server_passwords">
    <item quantity="one">server password</item>
    <item quantity="other">server passwords</item>
</plurals>
  <plurals name="settings_import_setting_passwords">
    <item quantity="one">Setting password…</item>
    <item quantity="other">Setting passwords…</item>
</plurals>
```

Comment: Did you try adding the missing quantities?

Comment: No I didn't will you please explain more ?

Comment: The error message is giving you other quantities to define, e.g., you defined "one" and "other", it's asking you to also define "few", "many", etc. I don't know how else to explain it. I don't know if this will resolve the problem, but it would most likely resolve the message you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Add it Like this:

```
  <plurals name="password">
        <item quantity="zero">تعيين كلمة المرور</item>
        <item quantity="one">تعيين كلمة المرور</item>
        <item quantity="two">تعيين كلمة المرور</item>
        <item quantity="few">تعيين كلمة المرور</item>
        <item quantity="many">تعيين كلمة المرور</item>
        <item quantity="other">تعيين كلمة المرور</item>
    </plurals>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
<plurals name="settings_import_server_passwords">
    <item quantity="zero">No password</item>
    <item quantity="one">server password</item>
    <item quantity="other">server passwords</item>
</plurals>
```

Please consider that, as far as I know, the zero setting is used only in Arabic.
To be honest I have always ignored this warning since the Arabic people that were checking the translations did not provide any special translation in my cases. You need to check whether in your case the Arabic version needs a special translation for one or more of the other cases.

Comment: I think you are right "tools:ignore="MissingQuantity" is the solution :)